# Excel365 CSV import retains delimiting quotes in text fieldsd

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file stored in UTF8 encoding, with fields delimited by commas, and text (and date) fields enclosed in double-quotes, like this:

```
12345,"First row column 2","2021-05-12", "First row column 4","£100" 
67890,"Second row column 2","2021-05-11", "Second row column 4","£200"
```

When I open this file in Excel365, the double-quotes are retained instead of being discarded as delimiters as I would expect. I cannot find any CSV import filter options (including in the Get Data From Text/CSV feature) which allow me to remove the double-quotes - which were only added in the first place to identify the column as text in the CSV file.

Can anyone provide help with removing the quotes automatically during the import process, or guidance on how to create a CSV file with delimiters that Excel will treat sensibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space between the separator and the first quote of the fourth column:

```
12345,"First row column 2","2021-05-12", "First row column 4","£100"

67890,"Second row column 2","2021-05-11", "Second row column 4","£200"
```

Most likely that is causing the problem (if that is also the case in your original data).

---

> which were only added in the first place to identify the column as
> text in the CSV file.

Quotes are not used to identify a column as text (in csv all columns are text and it is up to the appllication how to treat the data), but to allow possible separators inside the fields, like:

```
1234,"aaa,bbb"
```

So if you don't have separators inside the fields you don't need the quotes.

Comment: Spaces between the separator and the delimiter was exactly the problem - thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Open the CSV-File with an Editor. Copy everything into a new Excel-Sheet (Column A for example). Then select column A and use Data -> Text to Column. Selected Fixed -> next. Choose Comma as a delimiter and set the textqualifier to `"`.